# How to make the remove button function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the remove button work. Please advise.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/6yqhxa41/3/)

```
$("#add").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var div = $(".wrapper-formula > div").filter(":hidden");
   var hid = div.size();
   div.first().fadeIn();
   //hid == 1 ? $(this).fadeOut() : null;
});
//$('#remove').remove();
```

Comment: Don't put links on comments, edit your question and put your links there please.

Comment: Please don't just dump a fiddle in your question. Put the relevant code into the question

Comment: @Lixus you can't when it is a jsfiddle without code....

Comment: Forget about the link now...what is the actual problem, none is mentioned? Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: I think one of the rules here is to actually show what you've been trying, here you want people to make the code for you...

Comment: Well your remove button is not hooked up to a click event so that would be your first problem.

Answer (score 1):

You reverse what you had in your add click:

```js
$("#remove").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var div = $(".wrapper-formula > div").filter(":visible"); // get all visible
  div.last().fadeOut();                                     // fade out last
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yqhxa41/5/)